# Syntax Error in SQLITEDATABASE in Android

Tags: android, database

In My database I want to retrieve a row from my database  . For this I write a query :

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query("Author_table", column_name, "Author_name=?" , params, null , null , null) ;
```

By this I want to do the following query : "Select AID from Author_table where Author_name = Sultan" . But I have got anexception in SQLiteDatabase in android . Please suggest me what to do ??

Comment: mention the exception that you got

Comment: Better yet, look at the exception and try to understand it and fix it. (And post a question here when all else fails)

Comment: The exception shows that There is no table named "Author_table"  .But I am sure that the table exists . From this I guess that there is some error in query syntax .

Comment: can u show the code for creating table? are you using open helper or plain sql commands?

Comment: I have used SQLiteDatabase Browser to create that database .

Comment: wow thats a wrong way to go. Android API provides SQLiteOpenHelper class which you can subclass and easily create tables, do updates etc... ( i'm gonna put example in my answer below )

Comment: That means By creating database with SQLiteDatabase Browser I can not use this in my android code ??

Comment: I am not sure if you are able to do that, I only know that Android docs suggest use of SQLiteOpenHelper for all actions with database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Cursor c = db.query("Author_table", new String[] {"AID"}, "Author_name=?", new String[] {"Sultan"}, null, null, null);
```

## EDIT

SQLOpenHelper

```
import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Environment;

public class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 8;

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table USER( "
            + "username varchar(256) not null, " + "sex varchar(1) not null, "
            + "password varchar(64) not null, " + "active int not null"
            + ");";

    public OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion < 8) {
            // db update goes here and in onCreate() (for newly installed apps)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap string values in single quotes. Your query should look like

```
Select AID from Author_table where Author_name = 'Sultan';
```

instead of

```
Select AID from Author_table where Author_name = Sultan;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("Author_table", new String[] { "AID" },
                    "Author_name LIKE ?", new String[] { "%Sultan%" }, null, null,null);
```